# Use * as a wildcard when searching a SQL query with Greater than or Less than

Tags: c#, wildcard

I am looking to perform a greater than or less than search on multiple columns from an access database in C#.

So far I am trying to compare a chassis number value that is stored in a access database against a value in a textbox. If that value is greater than the textbox, this would then return the relevant data stored in the database to a gridview.

so far my code is:

```
 var sql = "SELECT * FROM [database] WHERE (Manufacturer ='" + comboBox3.Text +
     "' OR Manufacturer='*') AND (Model ='" + comboBox4.Text + "' OR Model='*') AND (Fuel ='" +
     textBox9.Text + "' OR Fuel='*') AND (Chassisno='*' OR (Chassisno > '" + textBox2.Text + "'))";
```

The code above is finding results, but the 'greater than' operator is being ignored.

Does anybody have any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Before writing one more line of code please take the time to research Sql Injection attacks and how to write parameter queries in Ado.Net.

Answer (score 2):

This portion:

```
Chassisno='*'
```

Causes the query to find anything.  Please remove that part of the query if you are truly only interested in finding values that are greater than Chassisno.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use * wild card with "=" , you should use "like" keyword :

```
.....OR Manufacturer like '*') AND (Model ='" + comboBox4.Text + "' OR Model like '*') AND (Fuel ='" +
 textBox9.Text + "' OR Fuel like '*') AND (Chassisno like'*'....
```

Comment: I think he's matching for a literal asterisk. The wildcard with `LIKE` is `%`.